How to maximize the sparsity of orthogonal matrix?
Given a unit vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it's needed to find an orthogonal matrix $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ ($m \leq n$) of maximum sparsity.
What are the bounds of sparsity for such matrix? What strategy should one use to construct such matrix from a given vector?

How $v$ is related to $Q$ ?

@Gil $Q$ is a sparse matrix built from a vector orthogonal to $v$.
